# Resized image does not appear in my project

Tags: image, windows-8, png, splash-screen

I am developping a metro application on w8.
My splash screen image was too little and appeared just in the middle of the screen.
What is requiered is a 620*300 px image so I changed the dimensions of my picture and replace it in the project asset folder without changing the name, I looked in the properties the picture is in fact 620*300 pixels, there isn't any error in appmanifest file but when I launch the program the image size is the same, nothing has changed.

What I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected behaviour.  The image will appear in the center of the screen with the background colour you specify in the manifest surrounding it.